# Selenium - Como iniciar usando o browser do Chrome nativo

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Gostaria de saber como iniciar o Selenium no Chrome Nativo. Não se trata de carregar um perfil, mas iniciar direto no Chrome "nativo".

código padrão para abrir o Chrome usando o Chrome Drive.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://github.com/")
```

Eu sei que isso é possível, pois existe uma empresa que construiu uma IDE que faz isso.
[IDE da empresa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj27x.png)

Comment: Não entendo o que você quis dizer com nativo. Porém, talvez tenha que apontar para o driver. ex.: `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")`

Comment: Nativo é o navegador padrão que nós usamos. Com tudo carregado. Essa empresa, quando vc inicia o bot na IDE deles, ele simplesmente abre uma aba na mesma janela padrão que estamos navegando.

Comment: Já por padrão, o webdriver abre um novo executável com aquela tarja preta "o navegador está sendo controlado por testes automatizados"

Comment: é como se eles não usassem o webdrive, mas o próprio executável do Chrome. Já tentei `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chrome.exe")`

Comment: Talvez [isso](https://medium.com/@robinclick/3-ways-of-attaching-to-existing-browsers-in-web-automation-4f3ce4e5161a) responda sua pergunta.